# Unable to deploy EVM contract on Astar

Tags: polkadot-js, evm, astar

I have cloned Astar and built it, after running the cloned Astar code i tried to deploy evm smart contract on it but it is showing Error **error:evm.balanceLow**. I have used SubWallet to create an evm and aster address.

[image]

Comment: Two questions to try to narrow down the issue:
- What is the balance of the origin of the extrinsic? Have you tried to increase it?
- Have you tried to increase the gas limit parameter? For example 10x and so on?

Comment: @Iker i have tried both and still getting the same error.

Comment: I would recommend following one of their tutorials first: https://docs.astar.network/wasm-smart-contracts/smart-contract-development/tutorials/polkadotjs-ui and make sure that works. You can see their fee calculation here: https://github.com/AstarNetwork/Astar/blob/7fc8fe70cfa7b97ffd02a1ddde913d7f30a0bb3b/runtime/astar/src/lib.rs#L580

Comment: @Bruno i am not deploying wasm smart contract i am trying to deploy EVM contract .

Comment: Ok, you can see that the EVM logic that throws that error is here: https://github.com/paritytech/frontier/blob/fed5e0a9577c10bea021721e8c2c5c378e16bf66/primitives/evm/src/validation.rs#L138 `who.balance < total_payment` so make sure `who.balance` is above `total_payment` and make sure `total_payment` is valid. You may want to see how Astar configured EVM: https://github.com/AstarNetwork/Astar/blob/master/runtime/astar/src/lib.rs#L704-L720

Answer (score 1):

To call this `create` extrinsic from the EVM pallet you need the local currency to pay fees for the extrinsic and the EVM currency to deploy the contract. Make sure both have balance.

You can query the ETH balance with this RPC call:

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"id":1, "jsonrpc":"2.0", "method": "eth_getBalance", "params": ["YOUR-ADDRESS"]}' http://localhost:9933/
```

When running the node locally, Astar has set up an account with funds, you can take the private key from [here](https://github.com/AstarNetwork/Astar/blob/master/bin/collator/src/local/chain_spec.rs#L63) an send funds to your account.

I also recommend to follow this tutorial from the Astar docs, [to deploy the Smart Contract using Remix](https://docs.astar.network/docs/EVM/first-contract/deploy-local)